# Sort month data in VueJS with data pulled from an axios request

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to sort a list of months which are pulled in using an axios request. The data is split and duplicates removed and displayed using the method 'uniquemonths'. The data is displayed using a vuejs multiselect component.

The problem I'm having is I'd like to display the months in the correct order. i.e. Jan, Feb, March etc. but it is displaying October, December, June etc

I can get the principal of the idea to work as a stand alone in the example 'v-for="monthNames in sortMonths()"' and it looks to the data 'monthNames'.

My issue is I dont know how to sort my 'uniquemonths' in the order I'd like. I hope I have provided enough code.

Any help appreciated!

**This concept works but I'm trying to translate it into my uniquemonths method**

```
<ul>
            <li v-for="monthNames in sortMonths()" :key="monthNames">
              {{ monthNames.month }}
            </li>
          </ul> 



 data: function () {
        return {
          monthNames: [
            { month: "January", position: "01" },
            { month: "February", position: "02" },
            { month: "March", position: "03" },
            { month: "April", position: "04" },
            { month: "May", position: "05" },
            { month: "June", position: "06" },
            { month: "July", position: "07" },
            { month: "August", position: "08" },
            { month: "September", position: "09" },
            { month: "October", position: "10" },
            { month: "November", position: "11" },
            { month: "December", position: "12" },
          ],
    }

  methods:{
...  sortMonths() {
              return this.monthNames.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.position > b.position ? 1 : -1;
              });
            },
}
```

**My current info**

```
 methods:{
    .....
     let months = [];
              metamonths.forEach((item) => {
                const splitArr = item.split(", ");
                months = months.concat(splitArr);
              });
    
              this.uniquemonths = months.filter(
                (months, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(months) === i
              );

}
```

Vue's multi select menu

```
<Multiselectstart
    role="listbox"
    aria-labelledby="Select a start month or months"
    aria-label="Start month menu"
    title="Select a start month"
    id="Startmonth"
    v-model="themonths"
    :options="uniquemonths"
    :close-on-select="false"
    mode="tags"
    :searchable="true"
    placeholder="Select a month(s)"
    :track-by="trackBy"
     @search-change="results"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try following code with sort applied on ***monthNames*** with *parseInt()* applied

```
monthNames: [
            { month: "February", position: "02" },
            { month: "January", position: "01" },
            { month: "March", position: "03" },
            { month: "April", position: "04" },
            { month: "May", position: "05" },
            { month: "June", position: "06" },
            { month: "July", position: "07" },
            { month: "August", position: "08" },
            { month: "September", position: "09" },
            { month: "October", position: "10" },
            { month: "November", position: "11" },
            { month: "December", position: "12" },
          ];


sortMonths() {
              return this.monthNames.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.position) - parseInt(b.position));
            },
```

I get following sorted output, refer month **02** and **01**

```
[
    {
        "month": "January",
        "position": "01"
    },
    {
        "month": "February",
        "position": "02"
    },
    {
        "month": "March",
        "position": "03"
    },
    {
        "month": "April",
        "position": "04"
    },
    {
        "month": "May",
        "position": "05"
    },
    {
        "month": "June",
        "position": "06"
    },
    {
        "month": "July",
        "position": "07"
    },
    {
        "month": "August",
        "position": "08"
    },
    {
        "month": "September",
        "position": "09"
    },
    {
        "month": "October",
        "position": "10"
    },
    {
        "month": "November",
        "position": "11"
    },
    {
        "month": "December",
        "position": "12"
    }
]
```

And I'm avid follower @[timeonsite.js](https://saleemkce.github.io/timeonsite)

Comment: yes, it works for me. I tried inserting duplicates; they are also in sorted order in month array.

Comment: In case **parstInt()** may cause a date type change issue in vue multi-selector, a map() function can be added as well in above code.

`monthNames.sort((a,b) => parseInt(a.position) - parseInt(b.position)).map(c => {(c.position).toString(); return c;});`

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I get it to look at my list of months in my multiselect?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure about the internals of Vue's multiselect element.